# How to use Coordinatorlayout with Linearlayout?

Tags: android, xml, material-design, android-linearlayout, android-coordinatorlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Surface"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.behavior.HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior"
            app:title="@string/app_name" />

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:defaultNavHost="true" />

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.behavior.HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_navigation" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This attribute `app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.behavior.HideBottomViewOnScrollBehavior"` does not work inside `LinearLayout`, I tried to put `BottomNavigationView` outside `LinearLayout`, and the attribute above worked but I want to put `FragmentContainerView` above `BottomNavigationView` and at the same time make the attribute above work. How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your code like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
      android:id="@+id/abl"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Surface"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            app:title="@string/app_name" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:defaultNavHost="true" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_navigation" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: `FragmentContainerView` must be between `Toolbar` and `BottomNavigationView`. Also `BottomNavigationView` must be at the bottom not at the top

Comment: @Iuq281 Ah, my bad just add this `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` line to `BottomNavigationView`.

Comment: I already added it before. The `FragmentContainerView` still not top of `BottomNavigationView`

Comment: @Iuq281 Do you mean on top as in front of? If you don't want the content of your fragment in the back of `BottomNavigationView`, just set the bottom padding of your fragment content whatever height of your `BottomNavigationView`. The default `BottomNavigationView` height should be this `?attr/actionBarSize`.

Comment: In `ConstraintLayout` I want `FragmentContainerView` takes this attribute `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomNavigationView"`, I want do something similar like this but using `CoordinatorLayout`

Comment: @Iuq281 Yes, I understand what your intention is. But you cannot do the same with coordinator layout. You have to have these 3 `AppBarLayout`, `FragmentContainerView`( this can be anything for your main content), and `BottomNavigationView` as direct child of `CoordinatorLayout`. You cannot put them in `LinearLayout` or any other `ViewGroup`, `CoordinatorLayout` will just recognize it as main content and any `app:layout_behavior` value wont work.

Comment: I don't know what is the benefit of `CoordinatorLayout` if we can't do that. Some of the content in `FragmentContainerView` will be hidden under `BottomNavigationView`, I think I'll remove Hide `BottomNavigationView` feature because there is no solution. Thanks

Comment: @Iuq281 Yes, that's basically Android Development in a nutshell. Sometime you still have to do the hard work just to achieve a simple thing that should have been there in the first place. If you insist on doing what you have described  just don't use `CoordinatorLayout` and you will have to implement the hide/show `BottomNavigationView` yourself, or use `MotionLayout`.

Comment: I'll do it using scroll listener

Comment: I found a simple trick to solve the problem, Look at my answer.

Comment: Hey @SovathnaHong Do you have any idea how can I solve this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72609914/11560810)

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple trick to solve the problem. Inside `FragmentContainerView` I'm showing a specific fragment and there is `NestedScrollView` inside the fragment.

I gave these attributes to the `NestedScrollView`

```
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:paddingBottom="Should be the same height of BottomNavigationView"
```

Now the content inside `FragmentContainerView` will be top of `BottomNavigationView` and never will touch `BottomNavigationView`.

**The disadvantages of this way**

- It will leave extra space in the bottom but mostly
  `BottomNavigationView` will cover it
- If you give background color for `NestedScrollView`, The color will
  touch `BottomNavigationView`

But at least it is working as I want.